# What will be the lower bound of $\left|h_{(w_b,w_t)}(s_i,p_i) \right|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, inner-products

I am given

[image]

and

[image]

How to find $\left|h_{(w_b,w_t)}(s_i,p_i) \right|  \leq $ ?

My attempt

$\left|h_{(w_b,w_t)}(s_i,p_i) \right| \leq {q \cdot \mathcal{C}}^{2}$ [ using cauchy]

Am I wrong? Here w are weights of neural net.

[More about DON](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03193#:%7E:text=A%20DeepONet%20consists%20of%20two,output%20functions%20(trunk%20net).)

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text and give a more complete explanation of this notation. DON is what? Not everyone has a machine learning background and knows the acronyms.

Comment: Already I got my required answer. It seems to me some people is there who can answer without having the knowledge you asked for :)

Comment: This makes it an expert-to-expert conversation with zero content a wider audience could be interested in. I voted to close this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply [use Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

$$\left|h_{(w_b,w_t)}(s_i,p_i) \right| \leq \|B_{w_{b}}(s)\| \cdot \|T_{w_{t}}(p)\| $$

we also know $$\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2 \le \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty. $$

So $$\left|h_{(w_b,w_t)}(s_i,p_i) \right| \leq \sqrt{\mathcal{q}} \mathcal{C} \cdot \sqrt{\mathcal{q}} \mathcal{C} $$

Comment: The inequality is called [Cauchy-Sc$\color{red}{h}$warz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: I think that was a typo. Anyways it is rendering the right information.

Comment: If you are unwilling to correct typographical errors in your answer, why should we assume that there are no mathematical errors?  Please correct the typo (also, names in English should be capitalized).